# Having trouble with an SQL Command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I am having trouble with a command in SQL Server 2012. The problem i am having is that when i try and run a case statement within a query the columns before the case statement then become unrecognized.

I have isolated the problem and found it to be this block:

```
  Select 
    [Address 1] + 
    Case 
      when [Address 2] = '' then ',' + [Address 2] 
      else '' end 
    Case 
      when Town <> '' then ',' + rtrim(Town) 
      else '' end 
    Case when County&lt;&gt;'' then ','+rtrim(County) else '' end
) as Address 
from Employees
```

Any help would be great because i am still learning SQL.

Here is the full code block:

```
Select 
  'Chorley' as [Site Address],
  [EmpID] as EmployeeID,
  [First Name],
  [Surname],
  Manager as [Manager directly over employee],
  Email,
  '' as WorkPhone,
  [Home Tel],
  [Mobile Tel], 
  (
    [Address 1] + 
    Case when [Address 2] = '' then ',' + [Address 2] else '' end 
    Case when Town <> '' then ',' + rtrim(Town) else '' end 
    Case when County&lt;&gt;'' then ','+rtrim(County) else '' end) as Address,
  Pcode,
  [NI No],
  DOB,
  [Job Title],
  [Start Date],
  [Hours Worked],
  [Days And Times] as DaysAndTimes,
  Holidays,
  '', 
  [Contract] as 'Contract'
from Employees 
where [Employment Status]<>'Leaver' 
Order By [Department], [SurName]
```

Comment: formatting your query would be a good idea.

Comment: Like i said ... i am still learning. Thank you for the advise though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use a + between the cases in order to concatenate:

Before

```
Select  [Address 1]+
        Case when [Address 2] = '' then ',' + [Address 2] else '' end 
        Case when Town <> '' then ',' + rtrim(Town) else '' end 
        Case when County<>'' then ','+rtrim(County) else '' end) as Address
from Employees
```

After

```
Select  [Address 1]+
        Case when [Address 2] = '' then ',' + [Address 2] else '' end +
        Case when Town <> '' then ',' + rtrim(Town) else '' end +
        Case when County<>'' then ','+rtrim(County) else '' end) as Address
from Employees
```

Comment: See the edited version. You didn't have the plus signs at the end of each Case statement.

Comment: Thank you for showing how it was done. Now i can use that when i need it again =].